# Sample code to split byte array into chunks and convert and append it to the string

Tags: .net, c#-2.0

I am loading a file into a byte array and then converting it to string using the following 
method.

```
string str1 = Convert.ToBase64String(fileBytes);
```

It works fine with the small files, but when the files fet too bigger like 170MB, the application throws 'system.outofmemory' exception.

So to avoid the problem, I am trying to break the byte array into chunks and convert and append it to the string. I need to make sure that I read all the chunks until append each chunk at the end of the string. Need the sample code for breaking into chunks and looping through..

Comment: It'll be something like a `while` loop, paired with a file read operation and the encoding step (and IIRC you need to choose the right chunk size, or the Base64 encoding won't be valid). Where exactly is the problem, and what have you got so far?

Answer (score 1):

- Use CharrArray Fixed Size to Store Result - Compute it from FileLen
- Use Bf size Factor 6 - 6 Bytes -> 8 Chr

---

```
char[] ChArr;
string Fname = @"File Location ...";
byte[] bf = new byte[0x60000]; // 128k * 3  - 6 Bytes -> 8 Asc64 chr
int pout = 0;
int pin = 0;
using (FileStream Fs = new FileStream(Fname, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    int TotalBytes = (int)Fs.Length;
    ChArr = new char[(int)(Math.Ceiling (TotalBytes / 3 )) * 4];
    while (pin < TotalBytes)
    {
        int bytesRead = Fs.Read(bf, 0, bf.Length);
        if (bytesRead <= 0) throw new Exception("Bof Found");

        int bw = Convert.ToBase64CharArray(bf, 0, bytesRead, ChArr, pout);
        pin += bytesRead;
        pout += bw;
    }
}
string s = new string(ChArr, 0, pout);
```

Comment: Byte Array : {0} -> AA==, {0,0} -> AAA=,  {0,0,0} -> AAAA

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response, the code worked as it is but had to convert TotalBytes to Decimal

Comment: Yes, or Divide by 3.0 to forze double division.

Comment: Also using integer division: new char[(TotalBytes+2) / 3  * 4];

Answer (score 0):

You could try working on a line by line basis:

```
using (var sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(filePath))
{
    var line = sr.ReadLine();
}
```